# Script doesn't write logs in .txt file

Tags: php

I have this code which logged if someone try to sql inject me. The problem is that doesn't want to write in that file. What can be the problem?

```
$queryString = strtolower($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);

if (strstr($queryString,"<") OR strstr($queryString,">") OR strstr($queryString,"(") OR       strstr($queryString,")") OR
strstr($queryString,"..") OR
strstr($queryString,"%") OR
strstr($queryString,"*") OR
strstr($queryString,"+") OR
strstr($queryString,"!") OR
strstr($queryString,"@")) {
$loc = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$date = date ("d-m-Y @ h:i:s");
$lfh = "try.txt";
$log = fopen ( $lfh,"a+" );
fputs ($log, "Attack Date: $date | Attacker IP: $ip | QueryString: $loc?=$queryString\n");
fclose($log);
echo "What are you doing?!"; exit;
```

The file is in the same folder.

@Niet the Dark Absol - >I use this to prevent sql injection. Is it good?

```
$username = htmlspecialchars(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, addslashes($_POST['username'])));
$password = sha1($_POST['password']);

$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".addSlashes($username)."' AND password='".addSlashes($password)."'");
```

Comment: Use `file_put_contents();` with the `FILE_APPEND` flag.

Comment: `"it doesn't want to write in that file"` - Don't anthropomorphize your code, it hates when you do that.  More to the point, can you describe the problem?  Is there an error in the PHP logs?  When you debug this, is that code reached at all?  Is the data what you expect it to be?  (Also, side note: This is *not* how one prevents SQL injection attacks.  Not at all.)

Comment: You shouldn't need to do this. You shouldn't care if someone tries to inject you, because you should have appropriate measures in place to prevent it - be it as ham-fisted as `mysql_real_escape_string` or as intricate as prepared statements, injections should be of no interest to you.

Comment: I include this file in every other file where someone can try to inject me. I get ""What are you doing?!" but nothing in try.txt file. That's all.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Depends on the purpose of the site. If a user was trying to cheat-the-system to give themselves goodies (or worse, ruin an experience for all the other users), wouldn't you want to punish/ban/delete/destroy them? This is assuming that there ARE injection prevention measures already in place.

Comment: @JordanHughMcKimm True, that's a possibility, but personally I let my game automatically enforce rules wherever possible, making cheating pointless.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol while i agree with the points you make, i'm interested to see where this post goes and what the OP plans to do with this data. This has made me wonder how many attempted SQL injections my own sites have received.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, I realy don't see what is wrong with that I want to log if someone try to SQL inject me and then try to restrict him from accessing my site.

Comment: @Goro In response to your escaping code... no, it's bad! What if my username is `O'really`? Your code would then search the database for a user called `O\\\&apos;really`, which, obviously would completely lock me out.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, this site has only one register user. Admin and that's me. There is no registration form and member area. Not yet. May be later but for now will be just like this-> one user(me)

Comment: Then why do you even have this? Just use a hardcoded password instead - no possibility to inject you if there's not even a username field to use as a vector!

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, well I still learning php and don't know really how to do it. How I will authenticate?

Comment: Personally I just do `if( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != "my IP address here") die();`, but that of course depends on you having a static IP and not trying to access your site from anywhere else :p Alternatively, just have a form with a single password input, and check `if( $_POST['password'] == "my password goes here")`

Comment: @Goro You should look into [PDO](http://uk1.php.net/PDO). If you're new, and don't yet understand classes/objects, it will be a bit of a hurdle, but it is most definitely worth the effort. It pretty much removes the headache of escaping/injection.

Comment: Anyway, back on topic. Have you tried out [file_put_contents();](http://uk1.php.net/file_put_contents)? If not, give it a try and let me know how it goes.

Comment: @Goro If i were you, i would continue using the login system you currently use.. especially if you plan to expand upon it at a later date. However I would greatly improve the security of your code - http://pastebin.com/9N5epGrG see how I changed your code here to decrease the likelyhood that malicious code can be entered. I'm by no means a skilled coder, but in my opinion its very easy and simple to achieve a very good level of security.

Comment: @JordanHughMcKimm, I will try it now. Danielsmile that's look nice. Thank's

Comment: @danielsmile, `Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object` and `Use of undefined constant PASSWORD_DEFAULT - assumed 'PASSWORD_DEFAULT'`

Comment: @Goro Hi Goro, what version of PHP are you running? password_hash is a relatively new function and this may be the cause of both the errors that you are experiencing

Comment: PHP Version 5.4.12 also get `Call to undefined function password_hash() `

Comment: I need version 5.5 of php for this but I found solution and now is working normaly. The solution is here [Compatibility with the password_* functions being worked on for PHP 5.5](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Answer (score 1):

You may right the script like this to save your txt file.

```
$arquivo = "Logger.txt"; 
$texto = "[".$hora."][".$ip."][".$_SESSION['username']."] > ".$msg." \n"; 
$manipular = fopen("$arquivo", "a+b"); 
fwrite($manipular, $texto); 
fclose($manipular);
```